# Neo4j 2.0: Matching nodes in a matrix to create relationships errors out

Tags: neo4j

when I run this cypher from the browser console, I get an `Unknown error`.  I'm not sure how to troubleshoot that.

```
MATCH (s:ContactMembership)
MATCH (contact:Contact {ContactId : s.ContactId})
MATCH (contactmembershiptype:ContactMembershipType 
       {ContactMembershipTypeId : s.ContactMembershipTypeId})
MERGE (contact)-[:CONTACT_CONTACTMEMBERSHIPTYPE 
      {ContactId : s.ContactId, ContactMembershipTypeId : s.ContactMembershipTypeId}]->
      (contactmembershiptype)
```

ContactMembership has about 52k nodes
Contact has 42k
ContactMembershipType has 6

Each contact can have multiple membership types so there can be multiple relationships but each contactMembership node has a single contactid.

Should I be using Create instead of merge??  Not sure how to get more detail on the `Unknown error`...

[image]

Comment: Check the logs and try the query in neo4j-shell (f.i. through the old webadmin interface) to get better error reporting.

Comment: It looks like the error is just a web browser timeout error.  The process completes (in a whopping 154 seconds).  Looks like I'm going to have to do this in batches...

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that the `Unknown Error` was just a timeout on the console window.  When running the command in the shell, I can see that it completes in just over 154 seconds.

It would be nice if the 2.0 browser console gave a better description of the error, like 'Timed out waiting for a response'.

Answer (score 0):

Try below :

```
MATCH (s:ContactMembership),(contact:Contact {ContactId : s.ContactId}),
       (contactmembershiptype:ContactMembershipType {ContactMembershipTypeId :
       s.ContactMembershipTypeId})
WITH s,contact,contactmembershiptype
MERGE (contact)-[:CONTACT_CONTACTMEMBERSHIPTYPE 
      {ContactId : s.ContactId, ContactMembershipTypeId : s.ContactMembershipTypeId}]->
      (contactmembershiptype)
```

Comment: No dice.  That's the exact same as the query above and returns the same error message `Unknown Error`.  I added a screenshot to my post above.